# Name dataframes within a list by their column names

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with multiple categorical variables and one continuous variable. I have generated all of the combinations of the categorical variables, like so:

```
library(DescTools)
data(mtcars)
data <- mtcars[, c(1,2,8:11)]

var.names <- colnames(data[,2:6])
x <- CombSet(var.names, c(2:5), repl = FALSE, ord = FALSE, as.list = TRUE)

head(x)
[[1]]
[1] "cyl" "vs" 

[[2]]
[1] "cyl" "am" 

[[3]]
[1] "cyl"  "gear"
```

I am writing a for loop that creates a list of dataframes based on each combination.

```
listofdfs <- list() 

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
y <- c(x[[i]], "mpg")
matchExpression <- paste(y, collapse = "|")
temp_df <- list(data %>% select(matches(matchExpression)))
listofdfs[[i]] <- temp_df 
}
```

I would like to name each dataframe using the unique column names. For example, dataframe 1 should be named "mpg|cyl|vs" and dataframe 2 should be named "mpg|cyl|am". I realize that I need another loop nested within the existing loop; however, I am having problems doing this.

Here is a failed attempt (that was added to the above code):

```
for (j in seq_along(listofdfs))
names(listofdfs) <- paste(colnames(listofdfs[[i]][[j]]), collapse = "|")
```

I don't often work with loops or lists of dataframes, so I realize I am probably making a simple mistake. Can anyone help?

Comment: `out <- setNames(unlist(listofdfs, recursive = FALSE), lapply(unlist(listofdfs, recursive = FALSE), function(x) paste(names(x), collapse = "|"))); out` ??

Comment: Yes! both of those work, thanks!!